# Intellij setup git macro

Tags: git, macros, ide, intellij-idea

I would like to know if its possible to setup a macro for git.
I want to be able to shortcut a git workflow :
for instance :

- git checkout b
- git pull
- git merge a
- git push
- git checkout a